# Install ubuntu with Windows 8 secure boot issue

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, multi-boot, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Lenovo laptop alongside Windows 8 which was already preinstalled. I chose **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8**. It went smoothly until I got a message: `Installation complete` and a **Restart** button. I clicked the Restart button.

After rebooting I got just a black screen. I waited a few minutes and the black screen remained unchanged. I did a hard power off by pushing the power button of my computer a few seconds, and restarted my computer. I clicked <kbd>F12</kbd> a "Boot manager screen" popped up with two options: Windows and Ubuntu. I chose Ubuntu, but after a few seconds Windows booted up.

I have tried a few times. Whatever I choose at boot manager, my laptop always boots to Windows. This is a screenshot of my Windows 8 system information:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try [disabling Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) in your firmware. Unfortunately, details of how to do this vary from one computer to another. The site to which I've linked describes one way to do it on one computer, but yours may well be very different.

If that fails, you could try running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on the computer. If it doesn't work with the default options, post back with the URL that Boot Repair provides; that will feed us technical details about your partitioning and boot loader situation.

Comment: It looks there is a much simpler solution to disbale secure boot

Comment: The solution to which you linked in your answer tells you how to enter your firmware's setup utility, but once you're in the firmware's setup utility, you're on your own -- as that site says, "each BIOS configuration utility is different. You’ll have to intuitively navigate through the interface with my vague directions." In other words, it's *not* simpler than what I've suggested; it just provides a roadmap of how to start from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution

[disable-secure-boot-in-windows-8](http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-secure-boot-in-windows-8/)

It is much simpler and very straightforward.

Thanks all for your help